# Pass Props StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i try to pass props on stacknavigator, here my code

```js
const MainCart = StackNavigator({
  Cart: {
    screen: CartScreen
  },
  Checkout: {
    screen: COScreen
  }

  /* how to pass 'myprops' in this area? */

});


export default class ReactNative_RefreshControl extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('ReactNative_RefreshControl this.props.myparam : ' + this.props.myparam);
    return <MainCart myprops = {
      this.props.myparam
    }
    />;

    //https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props
  }


}
```

how to pass 'myprops' on StackNavigator area?

thanks

Comment: you dont have to pass props to navigation area.

Comment: check this:  https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2823

Answer (score 39):

### **React Navigation < 5**

If you want to pass props in that place you have to use it like this.

```
const MainCart = StackNavigator({
 Cart: {
    screen: props=> <CartScreen {...props} screenProps={other required prop}>
 },
 Checkout: {
    screen: COScreen
 }
```

If you want to pass props when navigating the solution by Sagar Chavada is useful

### **React Navigation - 5**

You have to either use **React Context(recommended)** or a **render callback** to solve this. Documentation [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props)

Below example shows how to do with React Context

In your parent of the navigator file create a context

```
<AppContext.Provider value={other required prop}>
   <YourNavigator/>
</AppContext.Provider>
```

In your navigator file

```
const YourNavigator = () => (
  <AppStack.Navigator>
     <AppScreen.Screen name={"routeName"} component={AppContextWrapper}/>
  </AppStack.Navigator>

const AppContextWrapper = ({ navigation, route }) => (
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    {(other required prop) => (
       <YourScreenComponent {...other required prop}/>
    )}
  </AppContext.Consumer>
);
```

another easy (not recommended) - Callback method

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home">
  {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

> Note: By default, React Navigation applies optimizations to screen
>   components to prevent unnecessary renders. Using a render callback
>   removes those optimizations. So if you use a render callback, you'll
>   need to ensure that you use React.memo or React.PureComponent for your
>   screen components to avoid performance issues.

Comment: This is not working for me, I am able to see only navigation props.

Comment: What are the props you are sending?

Comment: what is the solution for react navigation 5?

Comment: @shan Added for React Navigation 5

Comment: @AshwinMothilal thanks for the answer. It looks like hack/workaround. Does the RN5 have a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: @shan I have added an example for one more way but using React Context library is the recommended way.

Comment: The documentation in [https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) was very useful for me to implement context approach

Answer (score 23):

For those who are looking for React Navigation 5

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen" headerMode="none">
 <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} initialParams={{'key':'value'}} />
 <Stack.Screen name="CodeVerificationScreen" component={CodeVerificationScreen} initialParams={{'key':'value'}} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

You can receive initial params in login.js

```
console.log(this.props.route.params.key)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
**React-navigation v3**
```

in your click event do like this:

```
    onPressed(movie){
        this.props.navigation.navigate(
          'screen',
          {movie: movie}
        });
      }

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onPressed(movie)}>
```

and in other screen you can set like this:

```
export default class NavigateTo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: this.props.navigation.state.params.movie.title,
        year: this.props.navigation.state.params.movie.year
    }
  }
```

movie is a json object that contain title, year, release date, earning, poster, etc..

this one is for old navigation:

```
onPressed(movie){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id:'page2',
      movie: movie
    });
  }
```

and in second screen:

```
this.state = {
        name: this.props.movie.title,
        email: this.props.movie.year
    }
```

now you can see the **difference**

if this not work than try like this

```
<Button title="Second" onPress={() => navigate("MainCart",{},
  {
    type: "Navigate",
    routeName: "Checkout",
    params: {name:"Jo"}
  }
)} />
```

check this for nested stack navigation
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/143

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to pass a function to show toast with conte for every component, I ended up achieving it by using screenProps and overriding each component:

```jsx
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

showToast = (text) => {
  this.refs.toast.show(text, DURATION.FOREVER);
};

render() {
  return <Provider store={store}>
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>[
      <MyAppNavigator showToast={this.showToast}/>,
      <Toast ref="toast"/>
      ]
    </View>
  </Provider>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1
  }
});


const createNavigator = (screenProps) => {
  const toastWrapper = (Component, props, screenProps) => {
    return <Component {...props} screenProps={screenProps}/>
  };
  return createStackNavigator({
    login: {
      screen: props => toastWrapper(LoginView, props, screenProps),
      navigationOptions: () => {
        return {header: null}
      }
    },
    map: {
      screen: props => toastWrapper(FieldMap, props, screenProps),
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'Map'
      })
    }
  })
};

const MyAppNavigator = (props) => {
  const AppNavigator = createNavigator(props);
  return <AppNavigator/>
};
```

Then from my component:

```js
this.props.screenProps.showToast("Logging you in");
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you want to pass the parameter **myTheme** via props through the navigation. On **React Navigation 5** you can do so

```
...    
const myTheme = {...}
 return(
        <ProfileStack.Navigator initialRouteName='ProfileWithSettings'>
           <ProfileStack.Screen name={'ProfileWithSettings'}>
                {props => <ProfileWithSettings {...props} theme={myTheme}/>}
           </ProfileStack.Screen>
        <ProfileStack.Navigator/>
    );
```

on the ProfileWithSettings component you could then refer to myTheme as follows:

```
this.props.theme
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to send props from main component to StackNavigator and then passing down to it's component, I used screenProps to do that.

Your main function should look like this:

```
render() {
    return <MainCart screenProps={this.props.params}
    />;
  }
```

After that in navigator screen you can access it like this:

```
this.props.screenProps.params
```

Comment: Both are correct but both are different things, you are sending screenProps from component to StackNavigator. I'm sending screenProps from StackNavigator to component.

Comment: yeah my problem was like sending props from the main component to stack navigator further passing down them to navigator's components.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer holds if you are trying to access the app level from a navigation view, however, if you want to simply change the header or something like that you don't have to pass the params to your navigator.

A little bit of React magic:

```jsx
export default class ReactNative_RefreshControl extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  //this function will override the navigation options specified in MainCart component
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: navigation.state.params.name,
      headerRight: <Button onPress={navigation.state.params.onClick}/>
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      name: "name",
      onClick: this.onClick
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Passing params from children of one **stackNavigator** to children of another **stackNavigator** in v5 **react-navigation**

```
const SecondStackNavigator = props => {
const stackOptions = {};
return (
  <Stack.Navigator headerMode={"none"} screenOptions={stackOptions}>

    <Stack.Screen name={"market"}>{() => <SecondScreen {...props} />}
   //Here the props is passed with spread operator to children 

  </Stack.Screen>
```

);
};

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is finding a solution for **react-navigation 6.x**:

According to [react-navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/):

> **Passing params to a previous screen​**
>
> Params aren't only useful for passing some data to a new screen, but they can also be useful to pass data to a previous screen too. For example, let's say you have a screen with a create post button, and the create post button opens a new screen to create a post. After creating the post, you want to pass the data for the post back to previous screen.
>
> To achieve this, you can use the navigate method, which acts like goBack if the screen already exists. You can pass the params with navigate to pass the data back:

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) {
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Create post"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreatePost')}
      />
      <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Post: {route.params?.post}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function CreatePostScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [postText, setPostText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        style={{ height: 200, padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        value={postText}
        onChangeText={setPostText}
      />
      <Button
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          // Pass and merge params back to home screen
          navigation.navigate({
            name: 'Home',
            params: { post: postText },
            merge: true,
          });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```