# Sharing state with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

What is the "smart/assumed" way to pass username and change setUsername in this case from/between the parent and friend component?

From what I understand it doesn't work the same with sharing from App.js when I use react navigation(?) so assume that the app includes only 3 components that share and sets state - would I have to use context/redux for this? Thank you

**App.js**

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('Testname'); 

        <Stack.Screen name="Parent" component={Parent}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Friend" component={Friend}/>
```

**Parent.js**

```
export const Parent = ({navigation}) => {
return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello user:</Text>
                <Button title="go to friend" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Friend")}/>
            </View>
```

**Friend.js**

```
export const Friend = () => {
return(
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>This is the Friend page</Text>
   <TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Does [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092045/8269427) answer your query?

Comment: Ah okay so I guess context is the way to go, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood the best approach is to use Context/Hooks.